# mySQL - grabbing data while ensuring a field is unique

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 tables

categories with fields "id, category, total"
users with fields "id, category_id, title"

Category is a list of categories that a user can select.
Every time a user pick a certain category, we increment the total counter. (i.e popularity)

How can I grab a unique user data per category based ordered by categories.total and also the user.id needs to be the latest?

This is what I have. Almost there except this grabs the first user id.

```
select users.id from users left join categories on users.category_id = categories.id group by users.category_id order by categories.total desc
```

To illustrate, here is an example:
categories table has the following values
id = 1, category = free, total = 3
id = 2, category = expensive, total = 1
id = 3, category = cute, total = 2

users table has the following values
id = 1, category_id = 1, title = aello
id = 2, category_id = 2, title = bello
id = 3, category_id = 3, title = zello
id = 4, category_id = 1, title = gello
id = 5, category_id = 3, title = cello
id = 6, category_id = 1, title = fello

The sql query that I have returns the following users: 1, 3, 2 (the first user to be associated with the category that has the most total)

However, what I want the result to be is: 6, 5, 2 (the LAST user to be associated with the category that has the most total)

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements confuse me... so I'm not sure if this will *really* accomplish what you want... but it should return (6,5,2) (in no particular order).  Add "ORDER BY category_id" or something, if ordering is important.

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM users
GROUP BY category_id;
```

---

To address your comment, try this (untested, as I don't have MySQL installed anywhere):

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id = (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM users
    GROUP BY category_id
);
```

Comment: this is super close. I just edited the question a little bit. MAX(id) does return the right id now. However, all the other fields associated with users are still the fields associated with "id" and not MAX(id)

Comment: That's because mysql's GROUP BY is very sloppy, and doesn't require you to GROUP BY or use an aggregate function, and instead just picks an (effectively) random result to plug in in these cases... you may be able to do what you want with a subselect...

Answer (score 1):

```
select users.id from users left join categories on users.category_id = categories.id group by users.category_id order by users.id, categories.total desc
```

... or maybe this, if you want to get the user ids to start from the lowest category amount to the highest.

```
select users.id from users left join categories on users.category_id = categories.id group by users.category_id order by categories.total asc
```